# after making Service Worker, my site only loads when I delete cache

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, netlify

I already deployed my app in Netlify and it worked well

But after managing Service worker to make it PWA, my app in netlify only loads when I refresh after deleting cache

My service worker code is like this

```
var CACHE_NAME = "pwa-task-manager";
var urlsToCache = ["/", "/completed"];
// Install a service worker
self.addEventListener("install", (event) => {
  // Perform install steps
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME),
    self.skipWaiting().then(function (cache) {
      console.log("Opened cache");
      return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
    })
  );
});
// Cache and return requests
self.addEventListener("fetch", (event) => {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request).then(function (response) {
      // Cache hit - return response
      if (response) {
        return response;
      }
      return fetch(event.request);
    })
  );
});
// Update a service worker
self.addEventListener("activate", (event) => {
  var cacheWhitelist = ["pwa-task-manager"];
  event.waitUntil(
    self.clients.claim(),
    caches.keys().then((cacheNames) => {
      return Promise.all(
        cacheNames.map((cacheName) => {
          if (cacheWhitelist.indexOf(cacheName) === -1) {
            return caches.delete(cacheName);
          }
        })
      );
    })
  );
});
```

I'm also getting error `Cannot read property 'addAll' of undefined`

Comment: Is your netlify app iis running on `HTTPS`?

Comment: yes it is running on https!

Comment: Please share your web app url.

Comment: actually it works now! I left the answer below!

Answer (score 0):

I changed my service worker codes like this, and it's working fine now

```
var CACHE_NAME = "pwa-task-manager";
var urlsToCache = ["/", "/completed"];
// Install a service worker
self.addEventListener("install", (event) => {
  // Perform install steps
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then(function (cache) {
      console.log("Opened cache");
      return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
    })
  );
});
// Cache and return requests
self.addEventListener("fetch", (event) => {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request).then(function (response) {
      // Cache hit - return response
      if (response) {
        return response;
      }
      return fetch(event.request);
    })
  );
});
// Update a service worker
self.addEventListener("activate", function (event) {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(function (cacheNames) {
      return Promise.all(
        cacheNames
          .filter(function (cacheName) {
            // Return true if you want to remove this cache,
            // but remember that caches are shared across
            // the whole origin
          })
          .map(function (cacheName) {
            return caches.delete(cacheName);
          })
      );
    })
  );
});
```